# Does Arnold say that Hardy is responsible for Ramanujan's untimely death?

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details, mathematics-social-history, ramanujan, vladimir-arnold

In [Yesterday and Long Ago](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540287346) (2007), mathematician [Vladimir Arnold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Arnold)  wrote:

> When I resided at Cambridge as a senior fellow of Trinity College,Indian colleagues told  me  some  details  of  [Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan)'s life which are  not well  known.
>
> Once  an  Indian  physicist  who  arrived  from  the  USA  visited Ramanujan in  Trinity.  The  room  of  his  friend  seemed  too  cold for  him,  but  Ramanujan  explained  that  he  felt  cold  only  at night - when  there  is  sometimes  frost  in  Cambridge!  The visitor  asked  to  be  shown  how  Ramanujan  slept,  and  found that  he  slept on blankets  and never  suspected  that he should have  covered  himself  with  them  (people in  Madras  never do this!).  That  is  why  he  felt  cold,  and  that  is  why  he  got ill  (it  seems  that  first  it  was  pneumonia  and  then tuberculosis)  and  died  at  a very  young  age.
>
> I  think  that  [Hardy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._H._Hardy)'s snobbery  and  his  inhuman  behavior  did not let him visit  his  sick student, who  lived  in the  same house, and  did not let him give  elementary practical  advice. While telling me  this  story,  my  Indian  colleagues  tactfully avoided  a discussion  of  British customs and  connected the  reason for Rarnanujan's  death  with  an  Indian  custom,  according to  which his  wife  did  not  follow  him,  but  stayed  in  Madras.  She  was supposed  to  take  care  of  her  mother-in-law,  Ramanujan's mother; this  duty  was  more  important  than  to  take  care  of her husband!  Since  that  time  Indian  students in Cambridge have been telling each other  how to make a bed and they do not feel cold anymore.

---

I have never heard this story before and was really surprised. How reliable are these facts and Arnold's explanations? Are there any other sources that corroborate these facts? Possibly that Indian  physicist mentioned by Arnold did write something about this?

I asked this question on MathOverflow but it was [closed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402838/does-arnold-say-that-hardy-is-responsible-for-ramanujans-untimely-death?noredirect=1#comment1030254_402838), because I had very little reputation they ruled the question is not suitable for their site.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think it is fairly obvious from the quote that Arnold is blaming Hardy's neglect for Ramanujan's  death. The real question is whether his charge is supported by evidence. Arnold's evidence comes from unnamed "Indian colleagues" who got it from also unnamed "Indian physicist", accompanied by his personal "it seems" diagnosis of  Ramanujan's ailment, and complete with also his "I think" theory about Hardy's behavior.

As it happens, documents concerning the final years of Ramanujan's life and his medical condition have been collected by [Rankin in Ramanujan as a patient](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02840652) and later analyzed by [Young in Ramanujan’s illness](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsnr.1994.0009). And there is plenty in them to tell that Arnold's anecdote is just out there.

For one, at Cambridge Hardy saw Ramanujan almost every day. As one can see from his correspondence with Ram and Thomson, Hardy was also closely following minutiae of Ramanujan's circumstances during his illness, including his stays, diet and specifics of diagnoses and changes in medical condition. He also advocated for his recognition by the college to provide moral support and remedy his depressions.

For two, Ramanujan spent more time at various nursing homes and other medical establishments than at Trinity. Even assuming that he could not figure out how to use blankets to stay warm, and could not get tips from anyone other than Hardy at Trinity, it is hard to believe that doctors would have missed that.

For three, there are plenty of other, well documented, factors that contributed to Ramanujan's medical problems, like malnourishment and sleep deprivation. His chronic depressions even led to a suicide attempt by falling in front of a train in a London subway station (the train stopped in time):

> "*It is clear that there were times when, because of the unavailability of acceptable Indian dishes, he was reduced to a very restricted diet of bread, milk and fried rice cakes (aplams). There is ample evidence that as a patient his recovery was retarded by his obstinacy in dietary and other matters. There is confirmation for this dating back to 1909 [10, p. 74], before he left India, throughout his time as a patient in Matlock (see below) and after his return to India in 1919.*"

> "*It is probable that Ramanujan's fits of depression were the result of the rather solitary life he lived while in Cambridge and in the various nursing homes where he was a patient. For this his working habits and vegetarianism were largely to blame. B M Wilson [W 107C, 11 (1-6)], who was an undergraduate in Trinity at the time, notes that Ramanujan was very rarely seen in Cambridge and that he sometimes worked for 30 or so hours at a stretch and then slept for 20.*" [quoted from Rankin]

And finally, the "first pneumonia then tuberculosis" has always been shaky:

> "*It appears that the first diagnosis of gastric ulcer was later changed, on not very firm evidence, to tuberculosis. By the end of 1918 his health had improved, and his election to the Royal Society and a Fellowship at Trinity may have been instrumental in this... Evidently, by this time the diagnosis of tuberculosis had been abandoned by his English doctors. On his return to India his health did not improve further, as had been hoped. Tuberculosis was again the preferred diagnosis.*"

Young speculates, based on detailed analysis of Ramanujan's medical history and symptoms, that Ramanujan had hepatic amebiasis, an aggressive infection of the large intestine that goes back to his 1906 bout of dysentery, of which his English doctors were unaware.